# Delete values in another table that appears once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
movie_id  rent_id
1            1
2            2
2            3
3            3
3            4
3            5

rent_id  client_id  
   1         1
   2         1
   3         2
   4         4
   5         4
```

I'm trying to `delete` in the second table a row which `movie_id = 2`, but only if the respective `rent_id` appears once. For example, I want to delete a movie, and if a rent is based only on this movie, it should delete on second table, but in the case  of `rent_id = 3`, I want keep it on the table, as there are other movies associated with it.

What I have tried is:

```
delete 
from en_aluguel 
where id_aluguel = (select id_aluguel 
                    from re_aluguel_filme 
                    where id_filme = 2 havin count(*) = 1);
```

but the result is not that I want

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
delete from en_aluguel 
where id_aluguel in (select id_aluguel 
                     from re_aluguel_filme 
                     group by id_aluguel
                     having count(*) = 1 and    -- only one filrm
                            min(id_filme) = 2  -- and that is film "2"
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
DELETE FROM en_aluguel e
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT movie_id, rent_id, 
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY rent_id) AS cnt
        FROM re_aluguel_filme
    ) r
    WHERE r.rent_id = e.rent_id
        AND r.movie_id = 2
        AND r.cnt = 1
);
```

Tested in [rextester](https://rextester.com/LUCL4822)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a group by to use having. Hope this works for you.

```
DELETE FROM public.movies
    WHERE movie_id in (select movie_id 
                         from movies 
                         group by movie_id 
                         having count(*) >= 2);
```